# How to restrict SFSafariViewController to only use WiFi?

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

Is it possible to make an instance of `SFSafariViewController` that will only use WiFi and not the cellular network?  If it's possible, how does one do so?

Comment: Why not let the user choose if your app can use cellular or not via the Settings page for your app?

Comment: @maddy I'm dealing with a hardware device to which I've created a WiFi connection using `NEHotspotConfiguration` and I want to display a web page served up by the device, but the URL works both on-device and on the internet (with the internet showing a page with info on how to set up the device).